# Website login for existing linux user

Tags: html, linux, apache, pam

I have a website and there is also a login form. I don't want to check it against my MySQL database with PHP, therefore I am looking for a way to check the user credentials to see if there is an existing Linux user already. I know `PAM` but I haven't found any information on how to check from a website against the `pam-module`. Any hints?

Comment: Do you want to authenticate or just check if a particular use exists ?

Comment: I wann to authenticate...

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://pecl.php.net/package/PAM) is a PAM module for PHP.